# Manual DAG run set individual task state

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG without a schedule (it is run manually as needed). It has many tasks. Sometimes I want to 'skip' some initial tasks by changing the task state to SUCCESS manually. Changing task state of a manually executed DAG fails, seemingly because of a bug in parsing the execution_date.

Is there another way to individually setting task states for a manually executed DAG?

Example run  below. The execution date of the Task is 01-13T17:27:13.130427, and I believe the milliseconds are not being parsed correctly.

### Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/jumpman_prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 2372, in set_task_instance_state
    execution_date = datetime.strptime(execution_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  File "/opt/conda/envs/jumpman_prod/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/jumpman_prod/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: ..130427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working from **Task Instances** page, but you can do it in another page:
- open DAG graph view
- select needed Run (screen 1) and click **go**
- select needed task
- in a popup window click **Mark success** (screen 2)
- then confirm.

PS it relates to airflow 1.9 version

Screen 1
[image: screen1]

Screen 2
[image: screen 2]

Answer (score 1):

What you may want to do to accomplish this is using *branching*, which, as the name suggests, allows you to follow different execution paths according to some conditions, just like an `if` in any programming language.

You can use the `BranchPythonOperator` (documented [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190403163651/https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.BranchPythonOperator)) to attain this goal: the idea is that this operator is configured by a `python_callable`, a function that outputs the `task_id` to execute next (which should, of course, be a task which is directly downstream from the `BranchPythonOperator` itself).

Using branching will set the `skipped` tasks to the proper state automatically, as mentioned in the documentation:

> All other “branches” or directly downstream tasks are marked with a state of `skipped` so that these paths can’t move forward. The `skipped` states are propagated downstream to allow for the DAG state to fill up and the DAG run’s state to be inferred.

The resulting DAG would look something like the following:

[image: branching]
<sub>(source: [apache.org](https://airflow.apache.org/_images/branch_good.png))</sub>

Branching is documented [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html?highlight=branching#branching), on the official Apache Airflow documentation.